# Do I need to include code to deal with failed PDO execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-handling

Lets say for simplicity I have the following code:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($SQL);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Do I need to provide code to deal with the statement failing to execute even if I've tested it extensively and ran into no problems?

I'm using mySQL exclusively.

I check all variables are in a format they are expected to be in before running (e.g check if needs to be an integer, string, regex tests etc)

I've never had an issue thus far with PDO statements not executing (unless I had an issue with my code), but I want to make sure no user at some random point in time encounters an issue with no error message.

Comment: Nah you don't need to unless you want your code to be **actually useful** for debugging when something inevitably goes wrong. However, I would definitely suggest programming in error checking and debugging methods.

Comment: "I want to make sure no user at some random point in time encounters an issue with no error message" - then yes. You need error reporting if you don't want users to be served a page with an error with no error code.

Comment: Then turn PDO::EXCEPTIONS On and write a global exception catcher that writes errors to a log file that you check regularly